# Time constant for diffusive process with radiation and convection

Tags: diffusion, thermal-conduction

I'm studying the thermal comportement of a "mass stove". I would like to do a materials selection. My first constraint is to have a temeperature of my "mass" between a lower and an upper born. I used this relation : $$Q_{fire} = ρ*c_p*dT$$

My second constraint is to stay above my upper born a certain time at minimum. I know that my temperature will follow this evolution : $$T(t) = (Q_{fire}/ρ*c_p*e*h)*exp(-\frac{t}{\tau})$$
And I was asking how to know tau ? I know that it should depend on the proprerties of the material especially his emissivity because of the radiation of the mass.
Thank you for your help !